# Was the power they received in Matthew 10 different from the one they received in Acts 2?

Tags: matthew, jesus, acts, pneumatology

Christ gives power to the disciples to cast out demons and heal the sick which was prior to the giving of the Holy Spirit.

Matthew 10:1 KJV

> 1 And when he had called unto him his twelve disciples, he gave them ***power against unclean spirits, to cast them out, and to heal all manner of sickness and all manner of disease.***

But later after receiving the promised Holy Spirit,the disciples perform more or less the same miracles that they had performed before receiving the Holy Spirit.

Acts 2:4,43 KJV

> .   4 And they were all filled with the Holy Ghost, and began to speak with other tongues, as the Spirit gave them utterance.43 And fear came upon every soul:  and ***many wonders and signs*** were done by the apostles

Was the power they received after the giving of the Holy Spirit different from the one they had received earlier?

Comment: The filling received in Acts 2:4 focuses on 'tongues' and 'utterance' so is the distinction a matter of _further_ powers ?

Comment: First, one has to be free of unclean spirits; but not being unclean is not quite the same as being squeaky clean, which is what being filled by the Holy Spirit implies.

Comment: Have you considered the contrast between "giving" and "filling?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Matthew 10 didn't include the Holy Spirit; Acts did

> [Acts 1:8](https://biblehub.com/acts/1-8.htm) But you will **receive power** when the Holy Spirit has come
>   upon you, and **you will be my witnesses** in Jerusalem and in all Judea
>   and Samaria, and to the end of the earth.”

Before [Acts 1:8](https://biblehub.com/acts/1-8.htm) we don't find the Holy Spirit coming upon people when the disciples preached the Gospel or laid hands on the believers. It happens afterward.

> [Acts 10:44](https://biblehub.com/acts/10-44.htm) While Peter was still saying these things, the Holy
>   Spirit fell on all who heard the word.
>
> [Acts 8:17](https://biblehub.com/acts/8-17.htm) Then they laid their hands on them and they received
>   the Holy Spirit.

We also find that it was only after the power received from the Holy Spirit the disciples were able to endure heavy persecutions with joy. Earlier all their preaching of Good news and working of miracles culminated in deserting Jesus when persecution arose as seen in

> [Matthew 26:56](https://biblehub.com/matthew/26-56.htm) But all this has taken place that the Scriptures of
>   the prophets might be fulfilled.” Then **all the disciples left him and
>   fled.**

But something tremendous happened after they received the **power of the Holy Spirit to be witnesses of Jesus**

> [Acts 5:40-41](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%205%3A40-41&version=ESV) English Standard Version (ESV) 40 and when they had
>   called in the apostles, **they beat them and charged them not to speak
>   in the name of Jesus**, and let them go. 41 Then they left the presence
>   of the council, **rejoicing that they were counted worthy to suffer
>   dishonor for the name.**

After the coming of the Holy Spirit in [Acts 1:8](https://biblehub.com/acts/1-8.htm) their experiences of power was not only ouward ( objective ) but also inward ( subjective ).

Change was from outward to inward. Samson experienced the Holy Spirit as a Spirit of might outwardly.

> [Judges 14:6](https://biblehub.com/judges/14-6.htm) And the **Spirit of the LORD came mightily** upon him,
>   and he rent him as he would have rent a kid, and he had nothing in his
>   hand: but he told not his father or his mother what he had done.

But we know that Samson was not mighty inwardly to endure temptation.
But the disciples with the **power of the Holy Spirit to be witnesses of Jesus** endure the sufferings of temptations, trials & persecutions with joy.

> [Colossians 1:10-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians%201:10-12&version=KJV) King James Version (KJV) 10 That ye might walk
>   worthy of the Lord unto all pleasing, being fruitful in every good
>   work, and increasing in the knowledge of God;
>
> 11 **Strengthened with all might, according to his glorious power, unto
>   all patience and longsuffering with joyfulness;**
>
> 12 Giving thanks unto the Father, which hath made us meet to be
>   partakers of the inheritance of the saints in light:

Before [Acts 1:8](https://biblehub.com/acts/1-8.htm) they could only be witnesses before people who saw only their outward lives. But by **power of the Holy Spirit to be witnesses of Jesus** the disciples were able to be witnesses before spiritual beings who saw all parts of their life.

> [Ephesians 3:9-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%203:9-11&version=KJV) King James Version (KJV) 9 And to make all men
>   see what is the fellowship of the mystery, which from the beginning of
>   the world hath been hid in God, who created all things by Jesus
>   Christ:
>
> 10 **To the intent that now unto the principalities and powers in
>   heavenly places might be known by the church the manifold wisdom of
>   God,**
>
> 11 According to the eternal purpose which he purposed in Christ Jesus
>   our Lord:

The changes were not only in power but also in outook and expectations:

1. From [Earthly](https://biblehub.com/matthew/24-1.htm) to [Heavenly](https://biblehub.com/revelation/21-22.htm)
2. From Physical to [Spiritual](https://biblehub.com/ephesians/2-22.htm)
3. From Temporal to Eternal [2 Corinthians 5:1](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/5-1.htm)
4. From merely posessing outwardy ( objective & shakable ) to
   possessing inwardly ( subjective & unshakable )

> [Hebrews 12:26-27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=hebrews%2012%3A26-27&version=KJV) King James Version (KJV) 26 Whose voice then shook
>   the earth: but now he hath promised, saying, Yet once more I shake not
>   the earth only, but also heaven.
>
> 27 And this word, Yet once more, signifieth the **removing of those
>   things that are shaken**, as of things that are made, **that those things
>   which cannot be shaken may remain.**

[The School of Christ
by T. Austin-Sparks](https://www.austin-sparks.net/english/books/school_of_christ_the.html) is a good book on this topic.